# symmetry in a differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $f$ a smooth function and $X$, $Y$ satisfying the differential equations:

$$ X''(t) + f(t)X(t) = 0 $$
$$ Y''(t) + f(1-t) Y(t) = 0 $$
with initial conditions
$$X(0) = Y(0) = 0 $$
$$X'(0) = Y'(0) = 1 $$
Prove that $X(1) = Y(1)$.

- If $f(t) = f(1-t)$ it is clearly true but I have no intuition why this should hold when $f(t) \neq f(1-t)$. I tried to write the problem in integral form:
  $$X(1) - X(0) = \int_0^1 X'(t) dt = \int_0^1 \left[X'(0) + \int_0^t X''(s) ds \right]dt \implies$$
  $$X(1) = 1 + \int_0^1 \int_0^t f(s)X(s) \,ds dt$$
  Then I would need to show that  $\int_0^1 \int_0^t f(s)X(s) \,dsdt = \int_0^1\int_0^t f(1-s) Y(s) \, ds dt$, but I couldn't progress.
- Another ideia was to use a change of variables $Z(t) = -Y(1-t)$. Then we get the system:
  $$\begin{cases} X''(t) + f(t)X(t) = 0 \\ Z''(t) + f(t)Z(t) = 0\end{cases}$$
  with conditions $X(0) = Z(1) = 0$ and $X'(0) = Z'(1) = 1$ and we want to prove that $X(0) + Z(1) =  0$. Then we consider the function $\varphi(s,t)$ such that $t \mapsto \varphi(s,t)$ is a solution to the equation $x(t)'' + f(t)x(t) = 0$ with conditions $x(s) = 0$ and $x'(s) = 1$. So we want to prove $\varphi(0,1) + \varphi(1,0) = 0$. If this holds, it is also true that  $\varphi(s,t) + \varphi(t,s) = 0$ for any $s,t$. Then I tried to check if the derivatives are zero, but couldn't proceed much longer.

Any tips are welcome. Thanks in advance and sorry about my poor english.

Comment: Actually, I just solved the problem, the second idea works with a bit more effort. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can finish the second idea using Abel's formula for the Wronskian, which in this case implies that the Wronskian is constant, i.e.
$$ X Z' - Y Z' = C, $$
if you replace $t = 0$ and $t = 1$, and using the initial and final values you obtain
$$ X(1) = C = -Z(0),$$
as you wanted to prove.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did in a roundabout way, this is a lot easier. I wasn't aware of Abel's formula and find out that XZ' - YZ' = c in another way. I was wondering if it was a coincidence. Now I know the result is even more general!